# Ms project - Avoid task split up in minutes

Tags: ms-project, tasks

I am trying to update my ms project plan with the following:
- replan al 0% and partly completed tasks from the new status date.
- Tasks can be split up
- Plan based on priority and available time for a resource

MS project has now the tendency to split up tasks in small pieces of minutes and assign 5 pieces of different tasks on 1 day why it should be possible to plan them in sequence without splitting them up. I did not use predecessor field as is most of the time I don't mind which tasks comes first as long as they are done and when a task starts it should be finished before starting another task.

Why i get now is the following below. I prefer that tasks are not split only when there is no other option. All tasks have a no start sooner than condition but not a fixed end date or dependency, so it should be possible to just plan them in a sequence to avoid over scheduling. 
Tasks needs to be split which have started last year but are not finished yet, these tasks should be split and take over to the next year.

Any advice would be appreciated

thanks

[image]